# How to optimize TCP / IP stack in Linux?

Tags: tcp, tcpip, memcached, udp, memcache

Currently I noticed there are about 15K open connections to localhost. It is mainly  connecting to Memcached. I am clueless where I should start to optimize TCP/IP stack. Memcached support UDP, but the PHP library doesn't support it.

The server has a lot of memory, about 7GB and it is dual core. Any pointers in how to optimize TCP / IP stack in Linux ?

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to optimize it?

Comment: Is this large number of connections on the stack causing slow downs for other services?

Comment: Doing performance testing, 39% of the time is spent getting data from memcached. To many open connections also causing the main site to slow down

Comment: What is the output of `netstat -natp | grep memcached | awk '{ print $6 }' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn`?

Answer (score 1):

Since memcached is running on the same server, consider configuring it (and your web app) to use a UNIX socket instead of network connections.

Answer (score 0):

What state are the connections in? If you only need more TCP connections (with identical source-destination pairs), ip_local_port_range might be something to look at: http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap6sec70.html . 
If you use connection tracking, http://www.faqs.org/docs/iptables/theconntrackentries.html might be useful. If you want to push the maximum connection/s, tcp_tw_recycle and tcp_tw_reuse might be interesting, but be careful with those and NAT.

Comment: I think the local port range is most likely to be your problem.